# ViewModel always return null or the problem might be my room query

Tags: android, repository, android-room, viewmodel

I'm trying to fetch a row using this query in my DAO (it might be also the problem here because I save date as String with this format yyyy-mm-dd)

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM stok_table WHERE kd_gas = :kode ORDER BY date(tgl_isi) DESC LIMIT 1")
    LiveData<ListViewModelStok> getTotal(int kode);
```

and here is my code for my Repository

```
public LiveData<ListViewModelStok> getTotal(int kode) {
        return stokDao.getTotal(kode);
    }
```

here is my code for my ViewModel

```
public LiveData<ListViewModelStok> getTotalGas(int kode){
        totalGas = repository.getTotal(kode);
        return totalGas;
    }
```

and lastly, the code for my fragment

```
mViewModel.getTotalGas(id_pilihan).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ListViewModelStok>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(ListViewModelStok listViewModelStok) {
                        int total = listViewModelStok.getTotal();
                        Log.d("DATA_ROW", String.valueOf(total));
                        total2[0] = total;
                    }
                });
```

thanks for your time

Comment: Debug your code. Make use of the Room Inspector Tool to figure out whether the query works or not, make use of Log Statements to figure out whether the data is available at viewModel and fragment or not

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I'd like to get example of the 2 method that you said. Or maybe I just have to type the keyword on google?

Comment: What is this!? int total = listViewModelStok.getTotal();.  Is it repository call!?

Comment: I don't see called this getTotalGas(int)

Comment: Instead of returning a local variable for Livedata, you can directly return the `repository.getTotal`.

Comment: @GobuCSG I'm trying to get a specific value from the listViewModel that retrieved from the observer. Is that possible or it's not? I'm kind of new to this so yeah..

Comment: @DarShan I will try out that

Comment: You haven't passed param to this method.  int total = listViewModelStok.getTotal();
In the DB if you've kode=0 you'll get record otherwise null. kode - int primitive type. I think that was your issue.

Comment: @GobuCSG I honestly still stuck, but I asked someone and they said I have to change the date to date type of data and not string first

Comment: Which result you're expecting!?  This one mViewModel.getTotalGas(id_pilihan) or listViewModelStok.getTotal();

Comment: @GobuCSG I want to get a certain value from a certain row, like if there is a table named stock, there would be id, type of gas and the total of gas, I want to get the total one so I made mViewModel.getTotalGas(id_pilihan) to get the data, I'm using LiveData<ListViewModelStok> in the DAO and I thought because the ListViewModel has getTotal, it would return the total of gas value that I set the id_pilihan param in. I hope what I said kind of makes sense.

Comment: Buddy, Date won't affect your query. You’re  returning same object only. Then y you need to call again...  If you don't have 0 in your table you're log value always null only.

Comment: int primitive type in your methods. you haven't passed any value inside observer 
int total = listViewModelStok.getTotal(); So, getTotal(int kode) will allocate 0. If you've doubt insert a row with kode =0. You can see result inside observer call.

Comment: @GobuCSG I found my problem, it's because I have to somehow insert this line in my dialogfragment `mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(StokViewModel.class);`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the simply by using sharedViewModel in the fragment. Thanks for everyone who tried to help! :)